# Ractivejs: How to get to work Nested properties in view

Tags: ractivejs

I have 2 objects `results` and `headers` being `headers` generated from `_.keys(result[0])`

```
r{
  data:{
    headers:['head1','head2']
    result:[
      {head1:'content1',head2:'content2'}
      {head1:'content3',head2:'content4'}
      {head1:'content5',head2:'content6'}
    ]
}
```

I have to create a table dinamically so I create this:

```
<table class="ui celled table segment">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    {{#headers}}
    <th>{{.}}</th>
    {{/headers}}
  </tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    {{#result:i}}
    <tr>
      {{#headers:h}}
        <td>{{????}}</td> <-- Here is where I fail to know what to put into
      {{/headers}}
    </tr>
    {{/result}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Can someone help me to fill in the blanks. So I can create a table that display the `contents`

If I remove the `{{#headers}}` part and I already know the elements `<td>{{.head1}}</td>` work perfectly the problem is that I'am generating different objects on the fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{{#result:i}}
  <tr>
    {{#headers:h}}
      <td>{{result[i][this]}}</td> 
    {{/headers}}
  </tr>
{{/result}}
```

The reason this works is that the `<td>` is repeated for each item in the `headers` array, because it's inside a `headers` section - so far, so obvious. Because of that, we can use `this` to refer to the current header (`head1`, `head2` etc). The trick is to get a reference to the current row - and because you've already created the `i` index reference, we can do that easily with `result[i]`. Hence `result[i][this]`.

Here's a demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rich_harris/dkQ5Z/